# How to link separated class for database operations in website in ASP.net with the pages.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> Login Page: when the user logs in I should check if password and user
>   name is true or not through checking the table records in database.
>   Because I'm working using oop concept I created a separate class for
>   DB operations but I face a big problem that the text boxes in the
>   `Login.aspx` can't be seen in database class. The with
>   `Registration.aspx` I want to insert data of the new user but I can't
>   see the textboxes to take the strings inside them to add in the
>   database any help or any way to link those classes together.
>
> here's my data Base class code
>
> ```
>  using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.IO; using
> ```
>
> System.Data.SqlClient; using System.Configuration; using
>   System.Data.Sql; using System.Data; using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
>   namespace Registration { };
>
> ///  /// Summary description for DataBase ///  /// 
>   //namespace Login.aspx { }; public class DataBase {
>       SqlDataReader rdr = null;    public SqlCommand cmd_insert;    public String USer="";    public String Pass="";
>
> ```
> SqlConnection conn = null;
>
> Login log = new Login();
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> public void Read_record()
> {
>     try
>     {
>
>         //string ID = Request.QueryString["id"];
>
>
>
>         conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIMOFCIS-PC\\MYSQL;Initial Catalog=WebSite;Integrated
> ```
>
> Security=SSPI");
>
> ```
>         SqlCommand cmd;
>         conn.Open();
>
>
>         cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserName,Password from Users ", conn);
>
>
>
>         rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>
>         //using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
>         //{
>             if (rdr.Read()) // you don't need while loop
>             {
>
>                  USer = rdr["UserName"].ToString();
>                  Pass = rdr["Password"].ToString();
>                  if (USer == log.UserName && Pass == log.Password)
>                  {
>                      rdr.Close();
>                      conn.Close();
>
>                  }
>
>
>
>
>             }
>
>
>
>         //}
>
>
>
>     }
>
>     finally
>     {
>         // close the reader
>         if (rdr != null)
>         {
>
>
>             rdr.Close();
>         }
>         // 5. Close the connection
>         if (conn != null)
>         {
>             conn.Close();
>
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> public void Insert_rows()
> {
>
>
>     conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIMOFCIS-PC\\MYSQL;Initial Catalog=WebSite;Integrated
> ```
>
> Security=SSPI");
>
> ```
>     conn.Open();
>
>     cmd_insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (UserName,Password,FullName,Address,Mobile,Email) VALUES (@value1 ,
> ```
>
> @value2 , @value3 , @value4 , @value5 , @value6 , @value7)", conn);
>
> ```
> } }
> ```
>
> and this alogin.aspx code
>
> `   using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using
>   System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls;
>
> public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page {
>       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>
> ```
> }
>
> protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
>
> {
>
>         DataBase db = new DataBase();
>         db.Read_record();
>         if (db.USer == Login1.UserName && db.Pass == Login1.Password)
>         {
>
>             Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx?UserName=" + Login1.UserName);
>
>         }
>
>
>
> } }`
> ```
>
> and in regestration.aspx i couldn't use create user control beacuse i
>   have to do specific fields to fill in so i couldn't depend on it to
>   solve the problem of not seein each like i do in login and it although
>   not working quiet well

Comment: Where is your code!? What have you tried, what is the exact problem.

Comment: Of course a 'separate' class cannot 'see' textboxes on a page. Are you asking how to pass parameters to class methods ? Please post your code.

Comment: Do not use the "quotes" for code. Use the {} or just indent by 4. Your code is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using an MVP pattern to separate the code, rather than a database class.  The database class won't be able to do it directly.  You can use a framework like [Nucleo MVP](http://nucleo.codeplex.com/) or [WebFormsMvp](http://webformsmvp.codeplex.com/).  For more on the MVP pattern, check out [Dino Esposito's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff955232.aspx).

Comment: and there's another problem  in one the registration web page  the  user must have two languages to choose one of them but i didn't have any idea how to do that how to change the page language by on click on any of two languages buttons So i didn't write any code and i don't know what to write in html file or in page.aspx.cs ......any help